# Can I remove inline event handlers using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML with an `onclick` attribute. I want to override that attribute using jQuery. Is there any way to remove the click handler using jQuery? Using [unbind doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/qu5zZ/1/).

Comment: I realise that, for a large site it might be unwieldy, but wouldn't it be easier (and lighter in terms of downloaded code bandwidth) to use Notepad/Textmate/Gedit (or any other text editor) to find all instances of 'onclick' (or onClick) and just remove them entirely?

Comment: @David - I'm dealing with inline crap generated by Rails 2. Once I've uploaded to Rails 3 I won't have this problem, as they've made all JavaScript unobtrusive.

Comment: ...I can't dismiss Rails (I've never really played with it, yet) but in response to its generation of 'inline crap' I can say only *ewwwwww*...

Comment: @David - to be honest, I think they've got most things right, but there was this obsession with inline JavaScript where they went really wrong. At least they're fixing it now!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try the [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) function:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

​
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qu5zZ/4/).

Once you've got rid of the `onclick` attribute you could attach your own click handler.

Comment: I have js inline  code on a tag  onclick="document.setLang{{ lang.1 }}.submit();return false;"  submiting a form but i can not stop submitting the form as you mentioned...

Comment: This solution may not work in Internet Explorer 8, 9 and 11. See note at http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/#entry-longdesc The solution from Abhishek Sinha is more error-proof

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#theElement")[0].onclick = function() {
  whatever();
};
// -- or --
$("#theElement")[0].onclick = null;
```

It's not that jQuery would make the standard DOM functions and properties go away. ;-)

Comment: you're right, but the nice thing about jQuery functions is that they apply to all the elements, so I can remove onclick from all matching elements without having to loo over them.

Comment: @Skilldrick: Technically, `removeAttr()` is a loop, too. But I agree it's more convenient that writing the loop yourself.

Answer (score 4):

As quoted in http://api.jquery.com/prop/ Removing an inline onclick event handler using .removeAttr() doesn't achieve the desired effect in Internet Explorer 8, 9 and 11. To avoid potential problems, use .prop() instead.

So this can be done as

```
$(function() {
    $('a').prop('onclick', false);
});
```

Comment: It is quoted in http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/ and the currently suggested code is `$element.prop( "onclick", null );`

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for it, but you should only do this when you really need to. The plugin gives you the option to call the old function or to ignore it entirely.

[jQuery Override Plugin](https://jqueryoverride.codeplex.com/)

```
$(divElementObj).override('onclick', 'click', function(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried given options but worked partially as they removed one but not all.

Instead I tried following chaining as workaround. I am using ver 1.4.2.

```
jQuery("selector")
    .removeAttr("onclick").removeAttr("onmouseout").removeAttr("onmouseover");
```