# Remove onmouseover event from all <img> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I doing this way:

```
$.each($('img'), function () {
    this.unbind('onmouseover');
});
```

This does not work. Why?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: `this` in the construct you're using, is the dom-element not the jquery object and thus there is no `unbind` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('img').unbind('mouseover');
```

No need for looping.. and also it should be `mouseover` not `onmouseover`

**Assumptions:** You are using `.bind` to bind the `mouseover` handler

> I'm not using bind. some images have onmouseover attribute and I want to delete them. I tries $('img').removeAttr('onmouseover') but it still does not work

1. Using inline event handler is not a standard.
2. Since you are using jQuery, you should bind handler like below.

**Code:**

```
$('img').on('mouseover', function () {
     //Your code
});
```

And later can unbind them by using `.off` ->

```
$('img').off('mouseover');
```

A work around for what you have (not preferred), ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846263/can-i-remove-inline-event-handlers-using-jquery))

```
$.each($('img'), function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('onmouseover');
});
```

Comment: I'm not using bind. some images have onmouseover attribute and I want to delete them. I tries $('img').removeAttr('onmouseover') but it still does not work

Comment: thanks very much. $('img').removeAttr('onmouseover') worked in my case, but I will consider that inline event handler is not preffered.

Answer (score 6):

- No need for [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) when a jQuery element collection already has an internal [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- Also, you can "daisy chain" remove handlers methods in jQuery since each function returns the same collection. Each attach method has it's own remove method pair, so use accordingly.

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) => [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
  - [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) => [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
  - [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) => [`die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/)
- Lastly, to remove the handlers on the DOM elements (the inline event handlers), replace it with null or a function that does `return false`;

Here's the concept code:

```
$('img')
    .unbind('mouseover')               //remove events attached with bind
    .off('mouseover')                  //remove events attached with on
    .die('mouseover');                 //remove events attached with live
    .each(function(i,el){              //and for each element
        el.onmouseover = null          //replace the onmouseover event
    });
```

Comment: +1, but is there a reason to assign a function to the `.onmouseover` property instead of `null`?

Comment: @amnotiam well you could assign null, but the `function(){return false}` was the way i knew how to do it.

Comment: @karaxuna I never knew `removeAttr()` removed handlers. Now I learned something new :)