# How to call inline onclick after external event - javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have an a button as follows:

```
<button onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this) " class="js-checkBackOrdered" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
```

And I have these JS codes:

```
jQuery(".js-checkBackOrdered").click(function(){

    if(jQuery("#backordered").length>0){
        showpopup();
        //should not execute the inline onclick here
    }
});

jQuery("#confirmbtn").click(function(){
    //execute the inline onclick event here
})

jQuery("#closebtn").click(function(){
    closepopup();
    //do not proceed with the inline onclick event
})
```

The problem I am having is, everytime I click on the button, the inline onclick is firing simultaneously with the external event.

How to stop this and execute the `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` afterwards?

Please help.

Comment: Can you remove the inline `onclick` attribute at all? If you're using external jQuery for some event handlers, you may as well use it for all of them.

Comment: You have two click handlers, both attached to the same element. A click fires both handlers. How else would it behave?

Comment: @Rory: thx for the tip, i have tried removing the attribute onclick onpage load, but cannot bind it properly afterwards..semms an issue with (this)

Comment: Sounds like you should start with removing the inline event first, then add your own. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846263/can-i-remove-inline-event-handlers-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to bind multiple handler to an event. you need to define you order in which to want to call them.
you can do it

```
<button class="js-checkBackOrdered" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
jQuery(".js-checkBackOrdered").click(function(){

        if(jQuery("#backordered").length>0){
            showpopup();
          }
          productAddToCartForm();
        });  
function productAddToCartForm(){
//you code
}
```

Comment: i totally agree with you, but since i do not have control of the html, i can only work with the external js to define/overwrite anything :(

Comment: why dont you place `if(jQuery("#backordered").length>0){
            showpopup();
          }` in start of `productAddToCartForm()`